# ViewPagerIndicator library configuration

Tags: android

When I add the ViewPagerIndicator library to a working android project, the project force close and does not work anymore.
When I remove the library the project works again.
I have those log error: http://pastesite.com/31448

Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks.

Edit: does Android work with Java 7 64bits? Maybe the problem is that...

Comment: May be i can help, if you post more detail i.e your `ViewPagerAdapter.class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using Eclipse.

First you have to create a ViewPagerIndicator android library project in Eclipse. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Then you have to go in your project to menu > Project > Properties > Android and in the Library section you have to add a reference to the ViewPagerIndicator library project. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

They say only JDK 5 and 6 are supported, but they do not say anything about JDK 7: http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same thing and I've finally got it figured out.

1. Must have 32 bit JDK. I uninstalled all my 64 bit stuff and now am strickly 32 bit.
2. Make sure the Java compiler is set to 1.6. `Right click the library project -> Properties -> Java Compiler.` That helps you get rid of the errors that deal with @override.