# Implement a page counter like the one in homescreen android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the homescreen . I got know that we can do that using a viewpager through this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008309/android-implement-a-page-counter-like-the-one-on-the-home-screen). I have already implemented the horizontally sliding homescreen using the viewflipper . i would like to like the same effect on my homescreen . Is there anyway of doing it

Thank you.