# Adding drawable to CirclePageIndicator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-viewpager

How to add image to circle pageindicator instead of adding color.. I have tried to add iconpage indicator but on click method is not working but i can add Image.. 
In circlepageIndicator onclick method is working but HOW TO ADD DRAWABLE, IMAGE TO CIRCLEPAGE INDICATOR. BELOW IS MY CODE.

[image]

USED CirclePageIndicator

```
       indicator  = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicatorMenu);
    indicator.setViewPager(pagerMenu);

    final float density1 = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    indicator.setRadius(5 * density1);
    indicator.setPageColor(0xFF000000);
    indicator.setFillColor(0xFF888888);
  indicator.setStrokeColor(0x880000FF);
    indicator.setStrokeWidth(2 * density1);

    //We set this on the indicator, NOT the pager
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {             
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
         //   Toast.makeText(HomeSpizzaView.this, "Changed to page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  pagerMenu.setCurrentItem(position, false);            
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {               
        }
    });

    indicator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentItem = pagerMenu.getCurrentItem();
               int totalItems = pagerMenu.getAdapter().getCount();
               int nextItem = (currentItem + 1) % totalItems;
               pagerMenu.setCurrentItem(nextItem);
         Log.i("kkkkk", "getCurrentItem"+  nextItem);
         Toast.makeText(HomeSpizzaView.this, "getCurrentItem"+  nextItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

USED  IconPageIndicator

```
      mIndicator  = (IconPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    mIndicator.setLongClickable(true);

    //We set this on the indicator, NOT the pager
    mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {             
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeSpizzaView.this, "Changed to page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);    
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {               
        }
    });


    mIndicator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentItem = pagerMenu.getCurrentItem();
               int totalItems = pagerMenu.getAdapter().getCount();
               int nextItem = (currentItem + 1) % totalItems;
               pagerMenu.setCurrentItem(nextItem);
         Log.i("mmmmmmmmmmmm", "getCurrentItem"+  nextItem);
         Toast.makeText(HomeSpizzaView.this, "getCurrentItem"+  nextItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use **CirclePageIndicator** object to customize page-indicator. you can set image or customize color. 
you can also customize these indicators using XML and you can find example from given link [Android-ViewPagerIndicator's GitHub](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator).
If you want to use icon or image then you can use following class [SampleIconsDefault.java](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleIconsDefault.java). from given sample

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only solution was to create my own library to do that.

https://github.com/augustopicciani/DrawablePageIndicator