# How to make a dot for highlighted title in PagerTitleStrip in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, pagertitlestrip

I am using PagerTitleStrip for swiping Fragment, I need to make a dot for selected item or Highlighted title.
My XML Code :

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blueColorSwipeText" />
```

I also need to change the highlighted title color.
Please help me out.
Thanks
Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problems have you encountered? Were you successful in creating a fork of `PagerTitleStrip`, for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008309/android-implement-a-page-counter-like-the-one-on-the-home-screen 
Try this

Comment: You want to replace the indicator bar with a dot, is that right ?

Comment: @vovahost . Yes that exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `textColor` attribute;
Create a new style in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="Pager">
    <item name="android:textColor">#4DB849</item>
    <item name="android:indicatorColor">#E95044</item>
</style>
```

You will get a green title and a red indicator.

You may want to see  [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

To change the indicator you have to change onDraw(Canvas canvas) method. 
Here is the source code [PagerTabStrip.java](http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/sources/android-17/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.java).

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final int height = getHeight();
    final int bottom = height;
    final int left = mCurrText.getLeft() - mTabPadding;
    final int right = mCurrText.getRight() + mTabPadding;
    final int top = bottom - mIndicatorHeight;

    mTabPaint.setColor(mTabAlpha << 24 | (mIndicatorColor & 0xFFFFFF));
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mTabPaint);

    if (mDrawFullUnderline) {
        mTabPaint.setColor(0xFF << 24 | (mIndicatorColor & 0xFFFFFF));
        canvas.drawRect(getPaddingLeft(), height - mFullUnderlineHeight,
                getWidth() - getPaddingRight(), height, mTabPaint);
    }
}
```

You have to change this line:

```
canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mTabPaint);
```

Test if you get a dot when replacing with:

```
canvas.drawCircle(left, top, 15, mTabPaint);
```

For drawing custom views check out the Android documentation.

[Custom Drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

Comment: I want a dot instead of indicator.