# ViewPagerIndicator won't add to project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to use Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator library.  I have created a new library project for it.  When I try to add it to Eclipse under `<ProjectProperties> -> Android -> Add` it gives me a green check mark.  When I click out of the menu and then go back, the library reference is gone.

When I then go to my Java Build Path, I see "library" under `Order and Export` and `Projects`.  I've read that it is bad to see if under `Projects` from this SO post: [Could not find Library.apk!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk)

I am also getting the error `Could not find library.apk!` from that SO question.  I have tried removing the library in `Projects`, but that just causes my imports to mess up.

After removing it from `Projects` and hovering over the Eclipse error and then selecting `Fix project setup` it recommends `Add project "library" to <my app>'s Build Path.`  This just brings me back to square one.

I have also tried this SO solution: [ViewPagerIndicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654201/viewpagerindicator)

That didn't change anything within my project.  I still get the `Could not find library.apk!` error.  When I get my app to run and compile, it gives me this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator`

Which I assume is just because my project settings are so messed up.  Any idea how to finally solve this?  I've been trying different things out for hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Project. Remove library.apk.

Comment: There is no library.apk there.  Only the library folder.

Comment: And more. The path should be relative to the library.
Check file "project.properties"

    android.library.reference.1 =../library-folder

Comment: Ok I removed it again.  "project.properties" only shows `target=android-15`.  Am I supposed to add the line you mentioned?

Comment: 1. You should keep an open project "ViewPagerIndicator-library". 2.Open properties project "ViewPagerIndicator-library" -> Android. And set "is Library" 3.Open properties of your project -> Android -> Add library. Okay to get.

Comment: I have the library project open alongside my normal Android project.  I double checked that "is Library" is checked.  I can add it to my project fine by going to "Add library" and it gives me a green check mark.  But as soon as I click Apply and then OK, if I go back to that screen the library reference is gone...

Comment: I fixed the problem!  The problem was that my version control program messed up the "readonly" settings on the files in my project folder.  I just selected all the files and made sure they weren't read only.  That was why Eclipse wouldn't add my library.  Thanks for the help.